# Can i write a function that throws exception which can be used in onCreate in android?

Tags: java, android

I am designing an API which takes Context as a parameter.

```
public myinit(Context context) throws SomeException
 {
        // Code Logic
        throw someException.
 }
```

**Question:**

Is is acceptable and best practice to invoke this `myinit()` in `onCreate()` of Activity which throws an exception.

Extremely sorry if it is a very basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do this, but you have to catch the exception and handle it or else if there are any un-handled exceptions your app will crash, you can handle exceptions like so .

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth);

    try {
        myinit(this)
    } catch(SomeException ex) {
        // Handle exception. Like do some UI notification if its a user input exception.
    }

}
```

If you were to not catch this exception your application would crash, if its a compile time exception your Android studio will give a red under line, and you wont be able to build the application unless you handle this exception. If its run time exception then it will build without any problems but if the function were to throw this exception at run time (for whatever reason) your application would crash.

And yes it is acceptible to do this, and the best practice is to handle this exception properly.

Comment: Thanks Bharagav for your instant reply.